# oci8 extension with nginx make bad gateway - mac m1

Tags: php, oracle, macos, nginx, oci8

sorry for the bad explanation and bad grammar

```
➜  project-name php --version
PHP 7.4.16 (cli) (built: Mar  4 2021 12:36:48) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.16, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

and i was trying too with v8

➜  ~ php --version
PHP 8.0.7 (cli) (built: Jun  3 2021 19:10:37) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.0.7, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.7, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

before i was trying with 3 version of oracle instant, sdk

- v11.1
- v12.2
- v19.8.0.0.0

i was checking my oci its working by running `composer require yajra/laravel-oci8:^7` where the command needed oci8.

```
➜  project-name pa package:discover --ansi
Discovered Package: facade/ignition
Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy
Discovered Package: fruitcake/laravel-cors
Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
Discovered Package: nesbot/carbon
Discovered Package: nunomaduro/collision
Discovered Package: yajra/laravel-oci8
Package manifest generated successfully.
```

but,,,

when i check on `phpinfo()` my page is going on `502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.19.8`

when i check on `oci_error()` the response is `false` thats mean there is no error, right ?.

when i comment `;extension=oci8.so` on `php.ini`
and

`➜  project-name brew services restart php@7.4`

`phpinfo()` is work but i need `oci_connect` function .

already tried restart, shutdown laptop , any service like nginx, php, still not solve,

when i check my logs on nginx or valet , there is no error or log

```
/usr/local/var/log/nginx
/opt/nginx/logs/error.log
```

my step install oci8 is
unzip oracle package `(instant,sdk,sqlplus)`

```
sudo ln -s /opt/instantclient_19_8/sdk/include/*.h /usr/local/include/
sudo ln -s /opt/instantclient_19_8/sqlplus /usr/local/bin/
sudo ln -s /opt/instantclient_19_8/*.dylib /usr/local/lib/
sudo ln -s /opt/instantclient_19_8/*.dylib.19.1 /usr/local/lib/
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libocci.dylib.19.1 /usr/local/lib/libocci.dylib
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libclntsh.dylib.19.1 /usr/local/lib/libclntsh.dylib
```

`sudo pecl install oci8-2.2.0` and i was try too with `sudo pecl install oci8 for php8 version`

my respond of oracle home `instantclient,/usr/local/lib`

the respond

```
Build process completed successfully
Installing '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.16/pecl/20190902/oci8.so'
install ok: channel://pecl.php.net/oci8-2.2.0
Extension oci8 enabled in php.ini
```

so i change

```
extension_dir = "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/php@7.4/7.4.16/pecl/20190902"
;extension_dir = "/opt/homebrew/lib/php/20190902"
```

but in php8 i don't need change the dir.

i run check oci like as what i was check on above.

[screenshot when test oci](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mQWo.jpg)

```
➜  ~ sudo nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /opt/homebrew/etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /opt/homebrew/etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

when i try check with phpinfo() condition is 502 bad gateway -> check with

```
<?php
if (oci_connect('xusername', 'xpassword', 'xip/XE', 'xcharset')) {
    print 'right';
} else {
    print 'error';
}
```

```
➜  oracle php -q b.php
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _OCIEnvNlsCreate
  Referenced from: /opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20200930/oci8.so
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _OCIEnvNlsCreate
  Referenced from: /opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20200930/oci8.so
  Expected in: flat namespace

[1]    35993 abort      php -q b.php
```

by reference on https://theoldape.com/mac-os-x-php-with-oracle-oci8-extension/ its mean wrong os version . hm
i have test with `instantclient-basic-macos.x64-19.8.0.0.0dbru` on my device mbp m1

in https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/downloads.html only
Instant Client for macOS (Intel x86) and
Instant Client for Mac OS X (PPC)

the problem i have found , its same like on [dyld: lazy symbol binding failed for php oic8 on Apple M1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65828380/dyld-lazy-symbol-binding-failed-for-php-oic8-on-apple-m1)

i have solved my phpinfo() with `instantclient-sqlplus-macosx-10.1.0.3` (Instant Client for Mac OS X (PPC))
so i can see oci8 table of configuration

then i try php -i **i have solved there is no error like as on** [dyld: lazy symbol binding failed for php oic8 on Apple M1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65828380/dyld-lazy-symbol-binding-failed-for-php-oic8-on-apple-m1) (dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _OCIClientVersion) ,

but when i try
`➜  oracle php -q b.php`
i still get error dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: **_OCIEnvNlsCreate**

Comment: Does command-line PHP work?

Comment: yeah work i was change with Instant Client for Mac OS X (PPC) version. but when try code with `oci_connect()` my page comback to 502 bad gateway against , try with `php -q b.php` like as explain on above i get error `_OCIEnvNlsCreate`

Comment: Are you comparing command line with web usage - please be clear what works and what doesn't?  Have you tried the Instant Client maOS Intel with Rosetta?  Does the Instant Client ARM package work?

Comment: what works
- i can run some command line where need oci8 require. for example `composer`
- `oci_error()` return false.
what doesn't
- i can't run some code `.php` with `oci_connect()` where i have enable oci8 extension.

i have tried test Instant Client with run sqlplus under rosetta get error `bad CPU type in executable:`  without that , i can remote my oracle server. thats mean my instant client its work ? sorry i am new on oracle.

Comment: Other people have been able to use the macOS Intel Instant Client SQL*Plus with Rosetta. I don't have access to M1 to comment further.

Comment: thanks in advance sir, i hope i can solve this problem, for while i use docker for work on oracle. what i research of part version oracle instant ,package instantclient-basic-macosx-10.1.0.3 is work on `php -i` but the version not compatible on m1 for `php function`, then > 10 version (v11, v12.1, v12.2, v19.8) is not work on `php -i ` (that's mean i can't run `phpinfo()` for seeing oci8 is enabled) but the version is compatible on m1.